# Migrate SQL server to SQL Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server, azure

If I use one of the methods to migrate a SQL server instance with several databases into a Azure Managed Instance, would the procedure also replicate any login accounts with access rights? 
Particular interested in knowing how this handles Active Directory accounts

Comment: Hi MadHalter, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, it doesn't and you cannot use Windows Authentication but only SQL Server Authentication or Azure AD. I've migrated several times a local database of my local SQL Server instance to Azure and I've done it using `Export Data-Tier` to `.bacpac` (this is the extension of the DB in `Azure`) and then deploying it (both actions from SSMS):

[image]

However, please be aware that you have to drop any users that use for authentication `Windows Authentication` because you'll get an error at the moment of deploying it since it cannot inherit your server's active directory settings. Then, you can define your own AD in Azure and use it.

Answer (score 0):

[Managed instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance) is a new deployment option of Azure SQL Database, providing near 100% compatibility with the latest SQL Server on-premises (Enterprise Edition) Database Engine.

The migration only support replicate the login.

You could get this from this document: [Tutorial: Migrate SQL Server to an Azure SQL Database managed instance offline using DMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-managed-instance#specify-source-details):

> By default, Azure Database Migration Service only supports migrating SQL logins. To enable support for migrating Windows logins, see the **Prerequisites** section of this tutorial.

That means you must re-create all the users and grant it access right(database roles) manually.

Hope this helps.